# Bad linebreak with tabulars in loop

Tags: tables, line-breaking, loops

I have built arrays (with csnames) containing contact information, and I would like to print out all the contacts in tabular format, using a loop.

But when the tabulars overflow the `\textwidth`, LaTeX allows one to stick out into the margin, and issues an "overfull `\hbox`" warning, rather than breaking early.

Why does it do this, and how should I fix it? (Perhaps a penalty setting?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\tableforloop}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
    First Lastname\\
    Address\\
    Phone\\
    E-mail\\
    \end{tabular}%
}
\newcounter{tablestoprint}
\newcommand{\printtables}[1]{%
    \setcounter{tablestoprint}{#1}%
    \noindent
    \loop
        \tableforloop\ %
        \addtocounter{tablestoprint}{-1}%
        \ifnum\value{tablestoprint} > 0%
    \repeat%
}
\newcommand{\myrule}{%
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\myrule

\printtables{2}

\bigskip
\myrule

\printtables{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic, but probably of relevance anyway: Selecting `l` as the column type for the inner `tabular` risks making the column widths very uneven. I'd suggest you load the `ragged2e` and `array` packages, issue the instruction `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}p{#1}}` in the preamble to define a new column type, and use `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}P{0.18\textwidth}@{}}` to define the structure of the inner tabulars. That way, the tabulars will never get too wide, and line breaking and hyphenation (if necessary) will be permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good break point, because stretching the interword space would exceed the `\tolerance`.

You'd get the same result trying to typeset

```
\noindent
\mbox{First Lastname\hspace{\tabcolsep}\ %
\mbox{First Lastname\hspace{\tabcolsep}\ %
\mbox{First Lastname\hspace{\tabcolsep}\ %
\mbox{First Lastname\hspace{\tabcolsep}\ %
\mbox{First Lastname\hspace{\tabcolsep}\ %
\mbox{First Lastname\hspace{\tabcolsep}
```

Use `\raggedright` or set `\spaceskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\tableforloop}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    First Lastname\\
    Address\\
    Phone\\
    E-mail\\
    \end{tabular}%
}
\newcounter{tablestoprint}
\newcommand{\printtables}[1]{%
    \setcounter{tablestoprint}{#1}%
    \noindent
    \loop
        \tableforloop\ \ %
        \addtocounter{tablestoprint}{-1}%
        \ifnum\value{tablestoprint} > 0%
    \repeat%
}
\newcommand{\myrule}{%
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\myrule

\printtables{2}

\bigskip
\myrule

{\raggedright\printtables{6}\par}

\bigskip
\myrule

{\spaceskip=.3em plus 3em \printtables{6}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]